# Opening a text file at a certain line (shortcut)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++, text-editors

I would like to define a shortcut key which opens a particular text file at a particular line. My preferred editor is Notepad++, but suggestions involving other editors are welcome.

How to open multiple files in Notepad++ each at a specific line ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You'll need to use the command line option listed in the [other answer](https://superuser.com/questions/290409/opening-a-text-file-at-a-certain-line-shortcut/290410#290410).

And then add a `Shortcut key` (aka Hotkey) to that Windows shortcut like so:

1. Make a shortcut to the program itself. You can do this by right clicking somewhere (desktop is easiest, but it doesn't really matter where) and choosing `New -> Shortcut`. You can also just find `Notepad++` in the `Start -> (All) Programs` menu, right click on the item, copy it from there, and then paste it.
2. Right click the new shortcut you've made (not the one in the Start Menu), choose `Properties`, and then go to the `Shortcut` tab. In the `Target` box you'll have something already there like `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"` You need to add your file you wish to open *after* the quote marks, and then `-n##` (replacing the `#`s with the line number). The target box should read something like `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" c:\users\username\desktop\test.txt -n73`
3. Stay on the `Shortcut` tab: there is a box for editing the `Shortcut key`. Click in there and type a letter. It will automatically add <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> to the front of it, and that is your shortcut key. I'm unsure if you can use any other combination keys for the shortcut key.

Comment: +1 for adding the other half of the answer that I didn't, and for providing so much detail.  Thanks!

Comment: What about nth character? Unity finds bugs with accuracy, including the character in the line as an variable, how can I open with NP++ on that linr AND character?

Answer (score 25):

You need to use the following command-line option (where "#" represents the line number):

```
-n#
```

The complete list of command-line options for Notepad++ is available in the project wiki:

[Controlling Notepad++ at startup by passing it Command Line Options](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/command-prompt/)

Comment: I know it's not the answer to the original question, but it was the answer to my questiion :-)

Answer (score 3):

To open multiple files each on a certain line with Notepad++:

```
// for each file (as command line):
notepad++.exe -multiInst filename -n#
```