# how to return to "last viewed line" on Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

i'm currently using the latest version of notepad++ portable. i remembered that the default behavior was that after closing notepad++ and reopening the same file again would lead me back to the same LINE (i.e. my last working location on the document, not referring to saved tabs).

i dived into the settings but could not find anything to enable that. help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any option in the program itself to return to the last edited line, although restoring the last open file is possible.

Try adding the **Session Manager** plugin:

[image: 1]

You can make it auto-save and auto-load sessions:

[image: 2]

Comment: hi there, i installed the 0.71 version of session manager, enabled autosave and autoload but it still doesn't go back to the last line where i was working on. any idea what i forgot to configure?

Comment: Works perfectly here with SM 0.7.1 in NP++ 6.2.3 (haven't updated to 6.3 yet). Are you sure you enabled both auto save and load? Is the session files folder writeable? Ensure that Session Manager is actually able to create session files in the folder you've specified. If it can't save, it obviously can't load.

Comment: yup it definitely can. it resides in my notepad++ folder (which is in the dropbox). used explorer to open it and it's accessible, but there are no sessions saved in the folder.

Comment: Well, I don't know what to say. I even downloaded [Notepad++ portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/development/notepadpp_portable) and tested Session Manager with it, and that works fine too.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific option for that (as far as I know), if you open a file after you closed the tab, it will go to the first line.

But the build in sessions save the "last used line" (even without the manager).

1) You can save the last state via the pref.:
Settings -> Preference -> Misc -> Enable "Remember current session for next launch"

2) You can manualy save the session through:
File -> Save Sessions... / Load Sessions...

3) Use the session manager as described in the other answer

this will save your tabs AND the line your were on.

Maybe this could help you as well, it opens a file on a certain line (via shortcut), but it's always the same: [Opening a text file at a certain line (shortcut)](https://superuser.com/questions/290409/opening-a-text-file-at-a-certain-line-shortcut)

Comment: yep, but i wouldn't want to save my tabs. i just want to save the state (i.e. last line for a particular file, automatically). thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post a comment, but I need 50 rep to do so.

Hence an "answer" instead.

I noticed that the cursor position is retained between saves/window changes if Word Wrap is disabled. Perhaps you can test if with Session Manager installed and Word Wrap disabled the cursor position is restored as well?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: JamesR404 already said he wanted to comment but couldn't. He should not be scolded for this attempt. You should allow anyone to comment. This one of the reasons Stackoverflow and Superuser are getting a bad reputation. Many people are now not asking helpful questions due to the arbitrary down votes.